# Objective-C Pointers > pointing to properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, pointers

I have an NSInteger property of a custom class called 'estimatedTime', now, in my UITableView class I'm trying to pass this property as a pointer to a UITableViewCell. I can't seem to get it to work! I've tried the following:

```
NSInteger *pointer = sharedManager.tempTask.&estimatedTime;
NSInteger *pointer = &sharedManager.tempTask.estimatedTime;
```

I get the errors: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
and: expected identifier before '&' token

Can you not pass a pointer to a property? Is the property not just it self pointing to the ivar in my custom class? I need it as a pointer type so I can edit the value when a UITextField is changed inside the UITableViewCell.

Thanks and hope it makes sense!

Comment: Think about what you are asking for.  Doing that kind of direct access violates every principal of object oriented encapsulation there is.  It'd break tons of stuff;  key-value observing, any kind of internal setter logic, validation, change notifications, delegation.... All likely broken.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Properties aren't variables; they are just syntactic sugar for get/set-style methods. Consequently, you can't take the address of a property.

Comment: So is there no way of getting the memory location for an ivar in a specific instance of my custom class?

Comment: If you own the class, then simply add a method that returns a pointer to the internal ivar.

Answer (score 3):

As Marcelo said, you can't do this using the property itself.

You would either have to:

1. Add a method to `tempTask` that returns a pointer to the `estimatedTime` iVar (`NSInteger *pointer = sharedManager.tempTask.estimatedTimePointer`)
2. Use a temporary `NSInteger`, taking its address for whatever calls you need, then copy the result into `estimatedTime`

Option 1 is probably a **really bad idea**, because it breaks object encapsulation.

Comment: While I agree that it's a _really_ bad idea (not just for encapsulation, but also with respect to object lifecycles and reference counted objects), it's arguably what NSData does, albeit only by having as an aim the ability to wrap C-style blocks of memory. So you can find precedent.

Comment: Bogus precedent.  NSData is immutable and, thus, is not an example.  NSMutableData does allow for this in a very specific, exceptional, case with several caveats about how problematic it is.  For regular ivars? No such compelling precedent exists.

Answer (score 0):

For using numbers in pointers I would suggest using a NSNumber* rather than a NSInteger* (an NSInteger is really an int). For example, if sharedManager.tempTask.estimatedTime is an NSInteger, you could do:

```
NSNumber *pointer = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sharedManager.tempTask.estimatedTime];
```

Now, when you want to use the int value for the number do:

```
NSInteger i = [n intValue];
```

The NSNumber * is a obj-c object so the usual retain/release/autorelease mechanisms apply.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you say Object1.Propertyxy.Property1

It is actually called as a FUNCTION rather than a VARIABLE/VALUE at some memory.

> In your case "tempTask" will act as a
>   function and "estimatedTime" as a
>   argument and the result would be the
>   RETURN of the function.

I know and completely agree that pointers are very favorable for increasing speed but in this case it is just useless as it would require storing that PROPERTY somewhere and thereafter referring to i, just a waste of time and memory, go for it only if you have to use that very specefic property a 100 times per run :D

Hope this helped, if it didn't just let me know, I'll be glad to help.